# Breeze JS: Is there a way to query entities from data.results?

Tags: javascript, breeze, single-page-application, hottowel

I have a Breeze web api controller, with methods that accept parameters and do some work, filtering, sorting, etc, on the server. 
On the querySucceeded, I'd like to do further querying to data.results. Is there a way to accomplish this? I got this working by exporting/importing data.results to a local manager, and do the projection from there. The projection is needed in order to use the observable collection in a vendor grid control.

```
        var query = datacontext.EntityQuery.from("GetActiveCustomers")
            .withParameters({ organizationID: "1" })
            .toType("Customer")
            .expand("Organization")
            .orderBy('name');

        var queryProjection = query
                .select("customerID, organizationID, name, isActive, organization.name");

        return manager.executeQuery(query)
            .then(querySucceeded)
            .fail(queryFailed);

        function querySucceeded(data) {
            var exportData = manager.exportEntities(data.results);
            var localManager = breeze.EntityManager.importEntities(exportData);
            var resultProjection = localManager.executeQueryLocally(queryProjection); 
    //This is the way I came up with to query data.results (exporting/importing the result entities to a local manager)
    //Is there a better way to do this? Querying directly data.results. Example: data.results.where(...).select("customerID, organizationID...)

            if (collectionObservable) {
                collectionObservable(resultProjection);
            }
            log('Retrieved Data from remote data source',
                data, true);

        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've taken an interesting approach. Normally a projection returns uncacheable objects, not entities. But you casted this to `Customer` (with the `toType` clause) which means you've created PARTIAL `Customer` entities with missing data.

I must hope you know what you are doing and have no intention of saving changes to these customer entities while they remain partial else calamity may ensue.

Note that when you imported the selected Customers to the "localManager" you did not bring along their related `Organization` entities. That means an expression such as `resultProjection[0].organization` will return null. That doesn't seem correct.

I understand that you want to hold on to a subset of the `Customer` partial entities and that there is no ***local*** query that could select that subset from cache because the selection criteria are only fully known on the server.

I think I would handle this need differently.

First, I would bury all of this logic inside the `DataContext` itself; the purpose of a `DataContext` is to encapsulate the details of data access so that callers (such as ViewModels) don't have to know internals. The `DataContext` is an example of the UnitOfWork (UoW) pattern, an abstraction that helps isolate the data access/manipulation concerns from ViewModel concerns.

Then I would store it either in a named array of the `DataContext` (DC) or of the ViewModel (VM), depending upon whether this subset was of narrow or broad interest in the application.

If only the VM instance cares about this subset, then the DC should return the `data.results` and let the VM hold them.

I do not understand why you are re-querying a local EntityManager for this set nor for why your local query is ALSO appling a projection ... which would return non-entity data objects to the caller. What is wrong with returning the (partial) Customer entities.

It seems you intend to further filter the subset on the client. Hey ... it's a JavaScript array. You can call `stuffArray.filter(filterFunction)`.

Sure that doesn't give you the Breeze LINQ-like query syntax ... but do you really need that? Why do you need ".select" over that set?

If that REALLY is your need, then I guess I understand why you're dumping the results into a separate EntityManager for local use. In that case, I believe you'll  need more code in your query callback method to import the related `Organization` entities into that local EM so that `someCustomer.organization` returns a value. The ever-increasing trickiness of this approach makes me uncomfortable but it is your application.

If you continue down this road, I strongly encourage you to encapsulate it either in the DC or in some kind of service class. I wouldn't want my VMs to know about any of these shenanigans.

Best of luck.

### Update 3 Oct 2013: Local cache query filtering on unmapped property

After sleeping on it, I have another idea for you that eliminates your need for a second EM in this use case.

You can add an unmapped property to the client-side `Customer` entity and set that property with a subset marker after querying the "GetActiveCustomers" endpoint on the server; you'd set the marker in the query callback.

Then you can compose a local query that filters on the marker value to ensure you only consider `Customer` objects from that subset.

> Reference the marker value only in local queries. I don't know if a remote query filtering on the marker value will fail or simply ignore that criterion.

You won't need a separate local EntityManager; the `Customer` entities in your main manager carry the evidence of the server-side filtering. Of course the server will never have to deal with your unmapped property value.

Yes, a breeze local query can target unmapped properties as well as mapped properties.

Here's a small demonstration. Register a custom constructor like this:

```
function Customer() { /* Custom constructor ... which you register with the metadataStore*/
    // Add unmapped 'subset' property to be queried locally.
    this.subset = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 3); // simulate values {1..3}
}
```

Later you query it locally. Here are examples of queries that do and do not reference that property:

```
// All customers in cache
var x = breeze.EntityQuery.from("Customers").using(manager).executeLocally();

// All customers in cache whose unmapped 'subset' property === 1.
var y = breeze.EntityQuery.from("Customers")
        .where("subset", 'eq', 1) // more criteria; knock yourself out
        .using(manager).executeLocally();
```

I trust you'll know how to set the `subset` property appropriately in your callback to our "GetActiveCustomers" query.

HTH

Comment: In the breeze controller, "GetActiveCustomers" returns IQueryable<Customer> entities from the entity framework:
It doesn't return partial customers. I removed last night the toType("Customer"), and added this instead:

           manager.metadataStore.setEntityTypeForResourceName("GetActiveCustomers", "Customer");

My breeze controller has several methods that return IQueryable<Customer> from the entity framework. That's why I had to use toType when using any of those resources, or using setEntityTypeForResourceName ( resourceName  entityTypeOrName ).

Comment: Regarding your question about why I need to requery the returned set of customer entities, is to do a projection (.select("column1, column2, etc")) to display the information in a vendor grid control, by simply having a knockout observable collection with the properties that I used in my projection (more info here: http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/knockout-circular-references ).

Comment: Both answers make sense to me.  I have another idea for you in the update

Comment: I will try your approach and let you know how it goes. I think it'll work fine. Just in case you are wondering, the reason why we're taking this approach is because we're targeting multiple clients in our line of business application (Single Page Application using Hot Towel template, Windows Phone, Windows 8 app), so we have code on the server that is reused not only in breeze controllers, but also in regular web api controllers, etc.

Comment: We have vendor grid controls (Kendo UI Web controls) with mainly three filtering options (Active, Inactive, All), that load entities by calling resource names like "GetActiveCustomers", "GetInactiveCustomers", "GetAllCustomers". Do you think this is the smartest way to handle this? By flagging the loaded entities with client side properties like your "this.subset"? I'd appreciate your opinion on this.

Comment: I suspect the best answer depends upon how many customers you have in cache. My instinct would be for the VM to hold an array of the `GetAllCustomers` entities in cache and pin these filtering options to an Array.filter function rather than incur what I imagine to be the extra overhead of requerying the cache. But that's an instinct. I have NOT measured these alternatives in any way and certainly not with a dataset that matches yours (about which I know nothing). This is not much of an opinion but there it is :)

Comment: Whenever I try to add an unmapped property with [unmapped] and the constructor in the metadatastore, the results have the property, but I can't actually query on it.

Answer (score 0):

Once you queried for some data breeze stores those entities on the local memory.

All you have to do is query locally when you need to filter the data some more.
You do this by specifying for the manager to query locally :

```
manager.executeQueryLocally(query);
```

Because querying from the database is done asynchronously you have to make sure that you retrieve from the local memory only if there is something there. Follow the promises.

Comment: The problem is that the server side function "GetActiveCustomers" did all the work. There's no code in the client to find these objects again, once they are cached. When the entities are loaded and cached on querySucceeded, the recently loaded entities are merged with the rest of the cached entities. I'd like to perform .selects, .where, etc, from data.results, without querying the local data to find these objects again.

Comment: can you provide a bit more details of what you are trying to do?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is something like: data.results.select("customerID, organizationID, name") on the querySucceeded.

Comment: `data.results` is an array witch contains all the entries that were retrieved. What could you do is to filter some more with JavaScript and return only what you need. For example: an entry has the folowing dependentObservables: `"customerID, name, isActive, organization.name"`. You could just encapsulate the ones you need `"customerID, name"` in a different array and return that one. You could even filter them again if you loop over the array and let's say : `if(data.results[index].customerID()===1)  newArray.push({customerID: data.results[index].customerID}, ...);`