# BreezeManager doesn't track changes with extended properties

Tags: breeze

I extended my server entity with some properties in the client side . 
When getting data from the query I really see these properties in the result filled with the proper values . 
When I change a value of an extended properties the manager doesn't track this change .
When I call manager.rejectChanges() no action is happen , I debugged the code and I see in the entityAspect.entityState ("Unchaged") although I modified the property.
If I modify a property comes from the server entity every thing is ok.

Here is my Product entity in the server :

```
public class Product
{
    public string Code {get;set;}
}

I extended the product in the client side with some others :
var Product = function () {    
        this.kind = ko.observable();
    };

breeze.metadataStore.registerEntityTypeCtor("Product", Product);
```

After the query I get both field (Code , Kind) , if I change Code , entity state is modified , I can call manager.rejectChanges and its takes effect, but if I change kind nothing happen , the entity state is "Unchaged".
Any idea why this happen ?
Thanks in advance ...

Comment: Breeze tracks navigation propertiesf or you.  What do you mean by 'extended property's?  As you know you need to show some code....

Comment: Please see my updated questing ...

Comment: Please see this question for a great answer from Ward on how to properly extend your Entities - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19123781/breeze-js-is-there-a-way-to-query-entities-from-data-results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By "extended" I assume you mean "unmapped" properties which are typically defined in a custom constructor as described in "[Extending Entities](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/extending-entities)"

"Unmapped" properties do not map to permanently stored values on the server. Therefore, changes to unmapped properties do not affect `EntityState` and they are not sent to the server.

Note that the server can supply the value of an unmapped property in the payload of a query and Breeze will set the unmapped property accordingly. This is a way to calculate non-persisted values on the server and transmit them to the entity on the client.

On the client an unmapped property behaves in other respects like a mapped property:

- conforms to the syntax of the model library (e.g., it becomes an observable in KO models)
- serialized when exported
- validation rules apply
- raises `propertyChange` when the value is changed
- entity remembers the property's "original value"
- `rejectChanges()` reverts the property to that original value

Comment: Ok , thanks , actually if I call entity.entityaspect.rejectchanges() it revert to the original values , but if I call the manager.rejectchanges() it's not . So this seems to be strange . With mapped properties I managed to do this in both way . But any way I managed to solve the issue with entity.entityaspect.rejectchanges().

Comment: What you described "cannot happen" ;-). `manager.rejectChanges()` and `entity.entityaspect.rejectchanges()` have the same effect on `entity`. There is no difference. I must assume that some code is different in the path between your tests of these variations.

Comment: Are you basically saying that the property has to come from the server to be tracked yet unmapped ?

Comment: is there any way to get breeze to send unmapped properties from the client? the docs state 'it may' .. kind of screwy.. I have some sideload data that I'd like to send up on the request that is intercepted but breeze won't send the data..