# breeze rejectChanges issue with unmapped properties

Tags: breeze

In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20595438/breezemanager-doesnt-track-changes-with-extended-properties), it was stated that:

- "On the client an unmapped property behaves in other respects like a mapped property"
- "rejectChanges() reverts the property to that original value"

I'm experiencing the same issue described in that question: EntityManager.rejectChanges() doesn't revert unmapped properties to the original value, while EntityAspect.rejectChanges() does.

In the responses to that question, it was suggested that this was probably due to a coding error.  I've made a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AkyQ9UmuLlIioA5bGKNi?p=info) demonstrating the issue.  Is there an error in my code that is causing this?

Edit - Updated Test Case:

```
    test("reject changes reverts an unmapped property - only unmapped property changed", 1, function () {
        var store = cloneModuleMetadataStore();

        var originalTime = new Date(2013, 0, 1);
        var Customer = function () {
            this.lastTouched = originalTime;
        };

        store.registerEntityTypeCtor("Customer", Customer);

        var manager = newEm(store);

        // create a fake customer
        var cust = manager.createEntity("Customer", { CompanyName: "Acme" },
                   EntityState.Unchanged);
        var touched = cust.lastTouched();

        // we change only the unmapped property (uncomment the next line and the test will pass)
        //cust.CompanyName("Beta");
        cust.lastTouched(new Date(touched.getTime() + 60000));

        //cust.entityAspect.rejectChanges(); // roll back name change
        manager.rejectChanges(); // would have same effect. Obviously less granular

        ok(originalTime === cust.lastTouched(),
            "'lastTouched' unmapped property should be rolled back. Started as {0}; now is {1}"
            .format(originalTime, cust.lastTouched()));
    });
```

you can see that in this environment, the test passes with entityAspect.rejectChanges(), but fails with manager.rejectChanges().  if a mapped property is changed along with the unmapped property, the test passes.

Comment: I'll try to take a look at this over the weekend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Updated answer 2/2/2014

Ok, what you have discovered is actually by design. *And.. thanks for the test above*, ( it makes understanding the issue much easier).

The issue here is that changes to unmapped properties do NOT change the EntityState of the entity. This decision was made because these changes do not actually ever need to be persisted to the server ( because there is nowhere to put them).

The second issue is that when calling EntityManager.rejectChanges we only process entities that have an Added, Modified or Deleted EntityState.  Since an entity whose ONLY change is to an unmapped property does not fall into this category, the entity level rejectChanges call is never made.

There are several workarounds.

- 1)  Call EntityAspect.setModified() after any change to an unmapped property. You can try this on the test above to see that it works. ( A slightly more complicated version of this is to use the EntityManager events to do this automatically).
- 2)  Change any mapped property whenever you change an unmapped one.
- 3)  Write your own EntityManager.rejectChanges that calls EntityAspect.rejectChanges on every entity in the EntityManager instead of just the 'changed' ones.  This does have perf implications so I don't really recommend it unless you have a very small cache.

Please feel free to suggest an alternative that makes sense to you.  We have considered adding settings to allow you to configure the treatment of unmapped properties. ( among these is whether an unmapped property change will change the entity state).

---

I can't repro this... and reviewing the code, the EntityManager.rejectChanges simply calls into the EntityAspect.rejectChanges for all **entities within the manager**.

So there are a couple of possibilities

1) The EntityAspect that you are NOT seeing rejectChanges work properly with is not actually "attached" to the EntityManager.

2) You are not actually comparing the behavior of "rejectChanges" on the SAME entity in both cases.

Take a look at the test cases within the DocCode sample in the Breeze zip.  These tests require no UI and are typically very short.  If you can paste a simple test here that fails in that environment, I will take a look.  Having a UI involved often clouds the picture.

Comment: I will take a look at the DocCode sample.  One thing though, to be clear: rejectChanges always works properly with EntityAspect.  it's with EntityManager.rejectChanges() that I'm not getting what I would expect.  The plunker i linked is a pretty simple test case (extremely limited UI).  I'll see if I can think of a way to paste an even simpler test.

Comment: Note: line 13166 of breeze.debug.js is "if (!this._hasChanges) return [];".  in my case, "this._hasChanges" is undefined, even though my entity has in fact changed (though the only change is to the unmapped property).  so, this could explain why it's not working despite it simply calling EntityAspect.rejectChanges for all entities... the manager isn't aware that any changed entities exist to call EntityAspect.rejectChanges for.

Comment: Have you checked whether the entity in question is attached to an EntityManager?.  i.e. aspect.EntityManager != null

Comment: the entities are definitely attached to a manager.  i forked the plunker to try to demonstrate that: [new plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DP3YAAfUhVGZZ2K8snBF?p=info)

Comment: here's a screenshot that shows the manager with "_hasChanges" undefined, the entities attached to the manager, and the entity clearly showing the unmapped property with a different value than the original value: [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/kQPVckE.jpg)

Comment: the test "reject changes should revert an unmapped property" covers this case. when i convert more or less the same test to use the "backingStore" model library, the test fails. i've edited my question with the modified test case.

Comment: Great, I'll take a look later today

Comment: i took another look at the test case, and the model library is not relevant.  i've updated the test case.  it looks like manager.rejectChanges() rolls back unmapped properties when a mapped property has also been changed, but not when only an unmapped property is changed.

Comment: Ok, I've updated the post above. Sorry for taking so long, been busy.

Comment: awesome, thanks for looking into it.  i've already proceeded with the approach of also updating a mapped property on the entities in question, and that works fine for me.